# MS Access- Generate fields in a form based on combobox choice

Tags: sql, sql-server, forms, ms-access, combobox

I'm using a linked view in Access from the SQL server.
That view contains an `employee_name` column and many other columns (like `equipment` , `parking`, `room`, `date` etc). There is a row for each new entry (for example an employee got a new phone at a date and then at another date he got another phone), therefore there are multiple rows for the same employee name.

What I need to achieve is having all the entries in a form from an employee.

What I have tried so far is creating a form based on that view and adding a combobox with the option "find a record on my form based on the value I selected in my combo box active". The problem was that I was seeing users multiple times due to the new enteries mentioned above. I fixed this by doing a `select distinct` on the employee name in the `row source` tab.
But now I'm getting only the first entry for an user, what I want is to get all the enteries (maybe in auto-generated textboxes, or anything which will be easy to export to excel, since that would be my next step - to have a button which can generate a report based on the user with all the corresponding entries) like I would have written SQL code like below:

`select * from schemaName.viewName
where employee_name = '/*here use the selected name in the combobox'`

Thank you for your help, I am a complete beginner to forms in Access and all of these great things one can achieve.

Comment: Is this a pass through query? Why do you use `schemaName.viewName`?

Comment: sounds like you really want 1 form built on the employees table (if exists or select distinct name and employeeid) with a subform that is built on your View of your the resources.  your subform will need to filter based on the unique id of the employee whatever that may be. here is microsofts tutorial on it. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b

Comment: @Brad I believe it's a linked server and not a pass through (saying I believe, because the file I am working on, already has a bunch of tables linked. It's just a view from sql server which you can access)

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the suggestion. It appears that something like that is what I need. I'll try the tutorial and let you know if that solved my problem.

Comment: I would like to avoid using subforms because then any modification brought to a form with subforms I have will then be performed on this too. I am not that sure about what I need because I'm not familiar with this part of ms access

Comment: I have no idea what your last statement of "I have will then be performed on this too" means.  Subform is most likely what you want . Unless you are going to do some VBA and manage it via code which if you think subform is too much wait till you look into vba.  If you build the subform and main form correctly you should only have to edit one of them when changes are desired.